# How should be the definition of dto to show an array of custom types in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, dto

There is a Country entity that has a border property. The border property is an array of Coordinate objects. when I want list the countries every thing is ok, but the border array will be empty on showing single Country.

Coordinate.type.ts :

```
export type Coordinate = {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
};
```

list.dto.ts :

```
export class ListDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsArray()
  @Type(() => CountryDto)
  items: Country;

  @Expose()
  meta: object;

  @Expose()
  links: object;
}
```

country.dto.ts :

```
export class CountryDto {
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  border: Coordinate[];
}
```

response of list :

```
{
  "message": "",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "sassdasdasdaad",
        "border": [
          {
            "lat": 11,
            "lng": 12
          },
          {
            "lat": 11.1231231,
            "lng": 12
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "iran",
        "border": [
          {
            "lat": 11,
            "lng": 12
          },
          {
            "lat": 11.1231231,
            "lng": 12
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "totalItems": 23,
      "itemCount": 2,
      "itemsPerPage": 2,
      "totalPages": 12,
      "currentPage": 1
    },
    "links": {
      "first": "http://localhost:3000/v1/countries?page=1&limit=2&limit=2",
      "previous": "",
      "next": "http://localhost:3000/v1/countries?page=1&limit=2&page=2&limit=2",
      "last": "http://localhost:3000/v1/countries?page=1&limit=2&page=12&limit=2"
    }
  }
}
```

response of get one country:

```
{
  "message": "",
  "statusCode": 201,
  "data": {
    "name": "ooo",
    "border": [
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, The object inside the second response is empty.
Does know anyone where is the problem?